# How to arrange copies in circle that includes the cloned object not at the centre

Tags: unity

I am using the editor code below to create copies of a game object in a circle with a given radius from the cloned object. The result is A in the image below, the cloned object at the centre with copies around. I want to achieve B, which has the game object (`CircleSpawn`) at the centre and the cloned object included in the copies that are created around the centre. The cloned object should be able to rotate and function in a way similar to it's copies. How can I fix my code to create this?

[image]

CircleSpawn

```
public class CircleSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{

public float radius, radiusLast, spin, spinLast;
public int numOfItems;
public GameObject clonedObject;
public List<GameObject> spawnedObjects;


}
```

CircleSpawnEditor

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(CircleSpawn))]
public class CircleSpawnEditor : Editor
{

public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    var tar = (CircleSpawn)target;
    tar.clonedObject = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(tar.clonedObject,
        typeof(GameObject), true);
    if (!tar.clonedObject) return;


    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Radius"); // Set as required
    tar.radius = EditorGUILayout.Slider(tar.radius, 0f, 5f);
    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Angle"); // Set as required
    tar.spin = EditorGUILayout.Slider(tar.spin, 0f, 360f);
    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Number of Items"); // Set as required
    tar.numOfItems = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider(tar.numOfItems, 0, 12);
    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Object");

    float angle, angleBetween = 360.0f / tar.numOfItems;

    if (tar.spawnedObjects == null)
        tar.spawnedObjects = new List<GameObject>();


    if (tar.spawnedObjects.Count != tar.numOfItems)
    {
        foreach (var ob in tar.spawnedObjects)
            DestroyImmediate(ob);

        tar.spawnedObjects.Clear();
        angle = 0f;

        for (int i = 0; i < tar.numOfItems; i++)
        {
            var rot = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, tar.spin + angle);
            var localPos = rot * Vector3.right * tar.radius;
            tar.spawnedObjects.Add(Instantiate(tar.clonedObject,
            tar.transform.position + localPos, rot));
            angle += angleBetween;


        }
    }


    if (!Mathf.Approximately(tar.spin, tar.spinLast) ||
        !Mathf.Approximately(tar.radius, tar.radiusLast))
    {
        tar.spinLast = tar.spin;
        tar.radiusLast = tar.radius;
        angle = 0f;

        for (int i = 0; i < tar.numOfItems; i++)
        {
            var rot = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, tar.spin + angle);
            var localPos = rot * Vector3.right * tar.radius;
            tar.spawnedObjects[i].transform.position =
            tar.transform.position + localPos;
            tar.spawnedObjects[i].transform.rotation = rot;
            angle += angleBetween;

        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. wow thanks for the code very interesting
2. As I understand it, you get version A because you add an object from the scene to the "clonedObject" field. You need to create a prefab of the target object and in the "clonedObject" field specify the prefab itself
   [image]